# Solving a large system of coupled differential equations using RK4

Tags: python, numerical-methods, differential-equations, runge-kutta

I want to solve a system of differential equations using the RK4 method, like given below. [image]

So for this case, I've to solve 3 differential equations-

d/dt(x0) = -2*x1

d/dt(x1) = -2* x0 -8* x1 -2√2*x2 and

d/dt(x2) = -2√2*x1 -14 *x2

Initial condition at t=0: x0, x1, x2 are -0.00076896, -0.01033249, -0.06899846 respectively.

Here, I am using M-matrix dimension 3x3 as an example. But for my actual problem, the dimension of the M matrix can be 100x100(M is a tridiagonal matrix). I can solve two coupled differential equations using [this process](https://www.nsc.liu.se/%7Eboein/f77to90/rk.html) but with this many equations, I have no idea how to even define them properly and solve using RK4.

Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: numpy provides matrix and vector operations, use these, see for instance https://stackoverflow.com/a/65085500/3088138. In an advanced version, use scipy.sparse. Then use any RK4 integrator with a standard interface, like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53650879/3088138 to get the numerical solution.

Comment: Or complete with time variable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47711186/rk4-python-explanation/47719747#47719747

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have used this for function definition
`def f(u):
    f0,f1,f2 = u   
    return (np.dot(M,u))`

It is solving for small dimensions, but what should I do for 100x100 case ?

Comment: You do not need the first statement, no need to unpack `u`, as the individual components are not used. Then changing the dimension is no problem.

Comment: Oh, I understood. Thank you very much for all your help!